# Force Windows Update to use specific internet connection (Windows 10)

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, internet

The question: Is there a way to force Windows Update to use a specific internet connection? I've tried ForceBindIP, but no dice.

The situation: I'm using Comcast's gigabit internet service, and I'm in an area with a 1 TB monthly internet cap. As I work with large files as part of my home office job, and enjoy HD streaming and gaming as well, I easily run into this cap on the regular. However, Comcast's "Xfinity Hotspot" program doesn't count against monthly data caps, and my neighbor has Xfinity, so... if I use their hotspot to pull Windows Updates and the like, while using my ethernet connection for other more time-sensitive or bandwidth-intensive tasks, I can considerably reduce the amount of my cap that's being taken up by Windows.

Similarly, outside of ForceBindIP, does anyone know of any good methods of routing certain programs through one internet connection or another? If I could make all of my non-speed-essential stuff use the Xfinity Hotspot connection, that could further reduce my usage of the data cap.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Classify the network you don't want to be used as metered. This will work for Windows Update, though probably not for other software.

Comment: Ooh. That's a simple but effective solution. Thanks. And while ForceBindIP is a bit finicky in my experience, I can probably make it work for other stuff.

Comment: Maybe you could add rules to the windows routing table.

Answer (score 0):

If your router supports it you could block the windows Update Servers.

- update.microsoft.com
- windowsupdate.microsoft.com
- windowsupdate.com
- download.windowsupdate.com

These might not be all servers.

Alternetivly you could stop the Update Services on the client PCs and activate them again when needed.